# Is there a way to see source code for android Photos app?

Tags: android, open-source, google-photos

I know android project is open-source project, so, I can see all code about it at the site as follows. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/
However, I cannot find the code for android Photos app.

[image]

Is there a site where I can see the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I cannot fine the code for android Photos app.

That is not part of Android. That is [Google Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos&hl=en), an app for Android distributed by Google through the Play Store, and pre-installed on some devices.

> Is there a site where I can see the code?

Presumably the code is in a Google office somewhere. :-)

Comment: It's too bad. Thanks anyway.

Comment: any ideas where to find a lib that would work as much efficient as gallery in the Photos app? I mean how the thumbnails are loaded and when you enter a specific photo - how you can zoom in and out?